# How to find port number of network connected device?

Tags: networking, network-programming, port

I connect the aggregator to my network. That IP address is 100.100.100.114. How do I know port number of connected devices to aggregator?

Comment: @shekharsuman there is no code I mean I want to know some method to get port number by cmd or some software

Answer (score 0):

You Can DownLoad the TCP view and in that you can see the list of the port that are listening to the IP address,

You can also use the nestat command for more details please refer
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490947.aspx

Comment: That software show when we give the some port number. But I want to know that aggregator protocols port number which coming from connected devices. When I give 100.100.100.114 IP address I want to know port numbers for that coming protocols. Ex. If I add modbus protocol device to aggregator or RS485 to Ethernet converter that default port number is 502. I want to see that port number

Comment: I got port scanner software thank you all for helping me